# formatted tab 3 10.1 and cant install android from twrp

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-3-10.1

got a problem with my samsung tab3 10.1 (5200), installed twrp and rooted the device and after that i formatted it in twrp to install a fresh android on an empty tablet. But install couldn't work , the installer couldn't make directories data and others so the install did not work ( took about 2 minutes) but at the end it says succesfull.
It cant boot past samsung logo because i think nothing really installed.
Anyone has an idea to try and install in another way ?
I'm trying to instal cwm now but says md5 hash invalid and same with the twrp file which is on the device.

Answer (score 0):

already found the problem guys, after the format  it sayd you best reboot the bootloader  so i did that and then it could read and write, it's up and running without the latest offcial update that crashed a lot.
rooted and deodexed whatever that means.
grtz